# Hashtable is not printing using JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am trying to display the hashtable using JSTL.
i have done as follows.

get the hashtable from servlet

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<% Hashtable EmpAttendanceHashTable = (Hashtable)request.getAttribute("EmpAttendanceHashTable");%>
```

Display the hastable on JSP.

```
<c:forEach items="${EmpAttendanceHashTable}" var="emp">
                <c:out value="${emp.key}" />
            </c:forEach>
```

But i can see the output as

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/ConditionalTagSupport
```

Comment: I think you are missing JSTL api in your runtime.Which version of servlet used in your application?

Comment: I have added jstl-1.2.jar in classpath.

Comment: What about the servlet version in your web.xml file ? See this http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info for better understanding.

Comment: I am using tomcat 7. how to check servlet version ?

Comment: Version is attribute of <web-app> Tag in web.xml file . Check it

Comment: my webApp is definde as <web-app id="WebApp" >

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37385/discussion-between-user1363086-and-satyam-koyani)